# Helm chart export syntax

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to export a helm chart to a folder. I've seen examples of using the command like this:

```
helm chart export mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/helm/hello-world:0.1.0 \   --destination ./install
```

What is the `"\"` between the chart's name and the `--destination` flag? Is the character a must for using the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume, you must have copied multi-line example, in bash `\` is used to split long single line into multiple one. You can remove it, if you run this command on the single line.